# The Mute Button Won't Mute AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, iphone, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

I need to loop play a .caf file in my iPhone app.

The AVAudioPlayer looks promising. But there's one problem. It won't stop or mute even if I pressed the mute button on the iPhone.

And I understand that there would be no way to programmatically find out whether that mute button is pressed or not in iOS 5.

So, what I need to know might be some properties about AVAudioPlayer or AVAudioSession. Or, perhaps, I may need to consider other libraries to loop playing my .caf file.

Any idea?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I realized it was because I had this line of code

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: nil];
```

I then changed it into

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error: nil];
```

Then the mute button would work and stop my AVAudioPlayer...

Answer (score 3):

From [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionCategoriesandModes/AudioSessionCategoriesandModes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH10-SW3):

[image]

So basically you just have to figure out which Audio Session category suits your need.

Comment: I can't find how to mute audio if silence mode off.) may be you know how?) category.ambient doesn't work )

Answer (score 0):

my 2 cents for swift 3.0:

```
let sharedSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

do {
    try sharedSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
} catch _{
    return false
}
```

or simpler:

```
try? sharedSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
```