# Swift - AVAudioPlayer doesn't play in background

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

Ok so Iv'e been trying to search for a solution for the past 2 hours but nothing had my problem fixed.
Solutions Iv'e tried:
- set the Background Modes to ON and check Audio, AirPlay, Picture...
- add to info.plist Required background modes and under that App plays audio using airplay

here's my code:

```
        do {

        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: destinationUrl!)
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()

        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do{
            try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        }catch{

        }
        print("starting to play...")

        audioPlayer.play()
        state = true
        started = true
        completionHandler()
    } catch let error {
        print(error)
    }
```

Thanks in advance for anyone trying to help.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31604629/audio-player-play-in-background-and-should-be-work-with-hardware-mute-switch?rq=1

Comment: it isn't, what im trying to do is keep playing a song while app enters background...